# How can I apply for an "on hold" problem to be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, reopen

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164215/how-can-i-show-the-time-derivative-of-an-energy-functional) was put on hold recently, which was reedited and adjusted by myself.

I do not question the decision but would appreciate any discuss on this issue. Also I would like to apply the question to be re-opened.

The question is not a homework (I am not sure whether it is "homework-like"). It is a calculation-oriented question based on fluid physics (I also cited a particular paper) so maybe that qualifies. It is certainly about physics and requests a definite proof or answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to apply anything, or apply for anything, if that's what you meant. Questions on hold that are edited are automatically placed in a queue to be reviewed by high-reputation users for taking off hold.

In its current form as I write this, I expect that the outcome of the review will be to leave the question on hold. Your question doesn't actually ask anything. All it says is "any hints will be appreciated", but that's not a question. (This is one of the common characteristics of bad homework-like questions.) You need to actually identify the concept that is confusing you and ask about that.

Comment: Hi, @David Z, thanks for your explanation. Do you think the line 13 in my post is a specific question? Frankly speaking, I just added "My question is" and highlighted it by boldface in my original post :)

Comment: OK, I missed that at first, but I don't think that quite makes it suitable for the site. (Maybe. I'm not sure.) Basically you've presented a problem you want to solve, you ask "How do I solve this?", then you go on to show some effort, but you don't ask about the specific step at which you get stuck. That's what you would need to do to make it a really good question.